# codeigniter $this->post->input is not posting full value

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a  text area for uploading embed code. when i post a embed code it is not posting full code.
this is my embed code

```
<iframe frameborder="0" width="480" height="308" src="http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/xt7dgo?autoplay=0&logo=0&hideInfos=1&start=0&syndication=108944&foreground=%23F7FFFD&highlight=%23FFC300&background=%23171D1B"></iframe>
```

This is my php code to get this .

```
public function embeded(){
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('video_heading', 'Video heading', 'required|trim|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('embeded', 'Embeded code', 'required|trim|xss_clean');
    $this->load->model('videos');
    $error['error']="";
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        $error['error']= validation_errors();
        $this->load->view('sidebar');
        $this->load->view('addvideo', $error);
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }else{
        //<iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Niiyh3sxwYk" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        $plink=$this->videos->processlink($this->input->post('embeded'));
        $info = array('heading'=>$this->input->post('video_heading'),
        'status'=>$this->input->post('status'),'video'=>$plink,
        'comment'=>$this->input->post('comment'),'category'=>$this->input->post('category'));   
        $this->load->model('videos');
        $obj= (object)$info;
        echo "opsted_link".str_replace("syndication","syndicate", $_POST['embeded']);
        if(isset($_POST['embeded']))
         {
              echo $_POST['embeded'];exit;
         }
        //$this->videos->addembededvideo($obj);
    }

}
```

When i use it i get the i frame code partially like this.

```
<iframe frameborder="0" width="480" height="308" src="http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/xt7dgo?autoplay=0&logo=0&hideInfos=1&start=0&syndicati></iframe>
```

i changed a parameter syndication=108944 in the src to syndicator=108944.

Now i get the full url !

is "syndication" is any reserved word?
Why this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a chance that your input is getting caught-up in the XSS filter. This is precisely what the XSS filter is designed to do; protect your site against cross-site scripting attacks. Try removing the `xss_clean` rule to test, but **take note**, to not put this into production.

My suggestion for you is to only send the video ID over HTTP (in your form). In this particular dailymotion video, you can find the ID: `xt7dgo`. It is really the only crucial piece of information in the `<iframe>` tag.

The rest of the attributes are autoplay, logo (on or off), hideInfo (on or off), start... etc. All of these attibutes can be re-created on the server. Use the server to echo out the `<iframe>` tag + submitted id + all the other attributes.

Comment: Thanks it is beacuse of this line                                 $this->form_validation->set_rules('embeded', 'Embeded code', 'required|trim|xss_clean'); i removed the xss_clean it is working fine now

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this.

This is the method which is in my controller:

```
function framex()
{
    $this->load->helper('form');
    if(isset($_POST['frame']))
    {
        echo $_POST['frame'];exit;
    }
    $this->load->view('deneme');
}
```

This is the view page:

```
<?php
    echo form_open('deneme/framex');
?>

<textarea name="frame"></textarea>

<?php 
    echo form_submit('submit','Submit');
    echo form_close();
?>
```

It worked!

Answer (score 0):

It's here, in `line 607` or in `2nd line` of `_remove_evil_attributes` function in `System/core/Security.php`, the bug exists. `xss_clean` was calling it.

```
$evil_attributes = array('on\w*', 'style', 'xmlns', 'formaction');
```

I don't even know if it's a bug. They are basically trying to provide security against

```
// All javascript event handlers (e.g. onload, onclick, onmouseover), style, and xmlns
```

So, I guess you'd have to do with it. Or, you could just change "syndication" to "syndicator" (like you are doing now) and convert it back after `xss_clean` to syndication.